# В Android функция RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(list.size()-1) не до конца опускает скролл в диалоговом окне

Tags: java, android

Я создаю RecyclerView со списком клиентов и помещаю его в диалоговое окно. Есть задача - опустить скролл максимально вниз. Делаю это при помощи функции RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(list.size()-1).

В случае, если RecyclerView расположен в xml файле активити - все нормально. У меня список из клиентов от 0 до 14. Указываю RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(14) и скролл опускается в самый низ.

[image: Все нормально, скролл внизу]

Теперь делаю inflate для нового RecyclerView и помещаю его в диалог. Адаптер тот же самый. Но когда я выполняю RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(14) то вижу следующую картину (скролл останавливается примерно на 13 позиции, хотя вручную я могу дотянуть его до самого низа):

[image: Скролл не до конца]

Возможно, это как-то связано с родителем RecyclerView (в одном случае - это активити, во втором - диалог). Такое впечатление, что RecyclerView "заезжает" под кнопки OK и CANCEL (пробовал и без кнопок сделать диалог, все-равно немного смещается вниз, такое впечатление, что до низа экрана телефона). Кстати, если поставить для RecyclerView фиксированную высоту (через recyclerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)), то проблема исчезает.

Я понимаю, что для решения проблемы можно установить высоту recyclerView вручную, но как узнать высоту диалогового окна без меню OK и CANCEL? Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

ОБНОВЛЕНО! Все больше склоняюсь к тому, что это реально баг RecyclerView. С ListView в моем случае все нормально (при использовании setSelection(14)). Но все-равно было бы интересно услышать мысли по этому поводу... И если это действительно баг, куда написать в гугл, чтобы его поправили?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580723/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-recyclerview-scrolltoposition-doesnt-work тут советуют сделать recyclerView.setStackFromEnd(true); но почему именно это помогает описано не очень понятно.

Comment: @GreyGoblin Да, это работает. Но в таком случае возникает другая проблема - когда ставлю RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0), скролл оказывается не на 0-м пункте списка, а немного ниже 1-го (то есть обратная ситуация получается).

Comment: вот поэтому я и не люблю такие вот мистические решения проблем. Как по бубну стукнул - вроде и помогло, но каким образом - не понятно. К сожалению помочь не смогу. Просто заинтересовала проблема и решил погуглить. То что выгуглил, то и предложил вам.

Comment: @GreyGoblin ничего мистического, setStackFromEnd просто указывает как заполняется список, сверху вниз или снизу в верх, и в варианте снизу в верх по умолчанию проскролен получается в самый низ. Никакой магии он действительно просто инвертирует ситуацию)

Comment: не знаю поможет ли это, но попробуйте выполнять строчку RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(14) в  recyclerView.post(new Runnable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-то будет интересно. Это был баг. Сменил версию RecyclerView на com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0 и проблема исчезла. Ранее использовалась библиотека com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего дело в том в какой момент вы скролите, скорее всего в случае диалога в момент скрола размеры RecyclerView полчаются ещё не окончательные, он скролит исходя из них, а после скрола его размеры уточняются и скрол несколько уезжает. Как вариант решения можно попробовать вызывать скрол с некоторой задержкой. К сожалению с текущей реализацией андройда необходимость задержек перед скролом это частый кейс(

Ещё можно попробовать подписаться на ивент onLayoutChanged у RecyclerView и скролиться там. Тогда вы сначала проскролитесь с промежуточными размерами, а потом и с итоговыми.

Comment: В принципе я и это предполагал. Однако проблема все-таки не в этом. Задержка скрола ни к чему не приводит. А вот onLayoutChanged действительно вызывается 2 раза. Но в обоих случаях показатели top и bottom одинаковые (то есть размер RecyclerView не меняется, и вызов RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(14)  ни к чему новому не приводит). Все еще склоняюсь, что это баг Андроида (а именно совместимость RecyclerView с диалоговым окном). Вот как бы разработчикам написать о этой проблеме? Может вы знаете, как обратиться в гугл с описанием бага?

Comment: @makandroid почитать о том как заводить баг для андройда можно [тут](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html). Но там надо будет очень детально описать как его воспроизвести.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ты выставил константные значения высоты и ширины в `XML` файлах для создания листа, это не баг. Попробуй поиграть с `wrap_content` и `match_parent`